# Run two computations in parallel, and return the results together

Tags: scala, thread-safety, concurrency

I am reading the "Learning Concurrent Programming in Scala" and there are exercises in the end of each chapter.
One of exercises is

> Implement a parallel method which takes two computation blocks a and
>   b, and starts each of them in a new thread. The method must return a
>   tuple with the result values of both the computations. It should have
>   the following signature: def parallel[A, B](a: => A, b: => B):(A, B)

I have implemented it in this way:

```
def parallel[A, B](a: => A, b: => B):(A, B) = {
  var aResult:Option[A] = Option.empty
  var bResult:Option[B] = Option.empty
  val t1 = thread{aResult = Some(a)}
  val t2 = thread{bResult = Some(b)}
  t1.join()
  t2.join()
  (aResult.get, bResult.get)
}
```

where `thread` is

```
def thread(block: =>Unit):Thread = {
  val t = new Thread{
    override def run(): Unit = block
  }
  t.start()
  t
}
```

My question is if this implementation is free of race condition? I have seen that other people had a similar implementations but declared result holder variables `aResult` and `bResult` to be `volatile`. I am not sure that this is necessary, and also I was not able to design a test which would break the correctness of my implementation.

From my point of view the implementation is free of race condition because the `parallel` method does not access any shared variables. All its state is in its local variables so is not shared. Thus I think that adding `@volatile` to `aResult` and `bResult` is not needed in this case.

Comment: "is good enough?"  That's a subjective question, one we can't answer with the current amount of information. Please clarify the title, since the rest of the question doesn't have the same issue.

Comment: Edited. I am interested if my implementation is free of race condition and if not then how to demonstrate it with some test.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask): "*State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.*". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Comment: Thanks for corrections and welcome words. Let's see know if someone can provide some constructive feedback :)

Answer (score 1):

> From my point of view the implementation is free of race condition because the parallel method does not access any shared variables. All its state is in its local variables so is not shared.

That is not true. The variable `aResult` is shared between the thread that called `parallel` and the thread `t1`. So there needs to be some synchronization between these two threads, otherwise you run into undefined behaviour.

---

This low-level JDK memory model gets tricky, so I would try to avoid it as far as possible, i.e. use higher-level abstractions and prefer immutable state.

I suppose the following (still rather low-level) tools (which would solve these issues) are not available for this exercise:

- Scala Futures
- Java Callables (which return a result instead of having to publish it somewhere)
- java.util.concurrent.AtomicReference (which you can use as a thread-safe holder if you have to use `Runnable` instead of `Callable`)

---

As for the specific question: According to the [Java Memory Model FAQ](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html)

> All actions in a thread happen before any other thread successfully returns from a `join()` on that thread.

Meaning that after your master thread has `join`ed the first worker thread, it *will* read the updated value of `aResult` without that field needing to be `volatile`.

So your code looks correct to me.

But I had to look this up. Really try to avoid mutable state when multiple threads are concerned.

Comment: Thilo, the point is that I am doing exercises which require to use low-level concurrency primitives. So I would not use them in real-life of course, but as far as I learn - I need to take this seriously and try to understand.
Also `parallel` is not a thread, but just a method.

Comment: `parallel` is a method, but some thread will be calling it. And this thread (which I called the "master thread" above) needs to communicate with the two threads started within the method. But according to the FAQ, it should work, because you use `join`. Without using thread synchronization (like `join`, `start`, `volatile` or `synchronized`) you have no guarantees that data properly gets passed between threads.